# Eclipse SpringIDE plugin does not support java-based spring configs

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, spring-ide

Any one knows if Eclipse SpringIDE plug in supports using Java-based Spring Config instead of xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Works very nicely, and a good deal faster than it is with XML configs.

Comment: how can I choose the java spring config files as my config ? now I go to Project->Properties->Spring->Beans Support, I choose the "Config Files" tab and click on "Add", it only shows me xml configs, I tried changing the "Configuration file suffixes" and put java (instead of xml) and then I clicked "scan", I got a dialog saying "No entries available". What am I missing?